# Why is it in electrocardiogram (ECG), we talk about the voltage generated by depolarisation of the heart is a vector and not a scalar?

Tags: potential, vectors, medical-physics

I'm asking to understand is the potential difference generated during depolarisation of the heart an exception to the rule that voltage is a scalar quantity? And if so, why?

I remember learning in my Physics class that potential difference is a scalar and not a vector, and this is supported by many sources on Google.

However, I often see that the average direction of the electric potential difference generated during depolarisation of the heart is a vector, sometimes termed the 'mean QRS vector' or 'instantaneous mean vector' or 'mean vector'. A picture is shown for illustration of how it acts like a vector which is denoted by the big black arrow.

Guyton and Hall defined a vector as *"A vector is an arrow that points in the direction of the electrical potential generated by the current flow, with the arrowhead in the positive direction. Also, by convention, the length of the arrow is drawn proportional to the voltage of the potential."* Based on this definition, then it would be valid to say the electric potential difference generated during depolarisation of the heart is indeed a vector but I'm not sure if this definition of a vector is itself valid. Alternatively, I'm thinking perhaps medicine has a different meaning for vectors different to the realm of physics.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Source: Guyton and Hall]

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, I've edited the title to spell out ECG. If readers are uncertain what QRS means, it cannot be spelled out but it effectively means the biphasic action potential of the heart ventricles, or in simpler term, it means the depolarisation of the heart ventricles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voltage represents an electrical potential difference between two points. In the case of an electrical circuit containing wires and discrete components like capacitors, resistors, etc. a voltage measured in the circuit is indeed a scalar quantity because in a circuit, directions don't matter, since the flow of electric current *in a wire* is one-dimensional.

But in a 3-dimensional hunk of meat full of salt water and goop, the current flow can take a variety of paths from one point to another, and if the voltage driving the current varies in position (as in the case of nerve impulses) then to completely describe the resulting voltage map over three dimensions of space and one of time, you need to specify the locations of the points at which you are doing the voltage measurement or, alternatively, the direction of the strongest current flow.

This makes a scalar quantity into a vector quantity.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially because charge is moving within the heart. If it was moving from the outside environment to/from the heart, you could model it as a scalar. But moving charge top/bottom, left/right, front/back are all different things.

It's more complicated than a vector. The charge distribution may be expanded as [multipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion). A vector represents the dipole term. I'd guess the reason you don't use the higher moments in cardiology is that they are weaker and more difficult to measure.

Comment: My apologies there’s quite a bit of jargon here so I don’t fully understand this. But are you saying that in the case of an ECG, this is a vector which is similar to electric dipole moment?

Comment: @BøbbyLeung Yes.